# Import LocalAuthentication.framework crashes on iPhone5s with iOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7.1, xcode6.1, touch-id

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426461/import-localauthentification-framework-crashes-on-ios-7-1) before but the selected answer and comments does not resolve the problem. So I am asking it again and going to keep it simple.

I have an app in which am using Touch ID. It works fine in all devices except iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.

To observe this thing.

1. Create a new Xcode project.
2. Add the LocalAuthentication framework.
3. Observe that the app crashes right away in iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.
4. Now mark LocalAuthentication as optional but it still crashes on that specific device.

**Note:** I also set **Link Frameworks Automatically** to NO in build settings. Then I had to add "**UIKit**" framework to app manully. Apart from that I did nothing.

[image]

[image]

I also tried the same thing with apple [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/keychaintouchidusingtouchidwithkeychainandlocalauthentication.zip), it is also crashing for the same.

Crash Log:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_isAuto
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Provide details from the crash. What's the full and exact error?

Comment: I have added the details. The app crashes right away. @rmaddy

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505658/xcode-6-1-iphone-5s-simulator-crash

Comment: So your issue is with the simulator, not a real iPhone 5s, correct?

Comment: yes i have tested it on simulator only. And the question that you suggested does not provide any solution. I commented there few days back. Its also not working Xcode 6.0.1 though.

Comment: The solution is to test on a real device. The problem seems to only happen with the simulator.

Comment: Same here. Facing this for more than a week

Comment: It won't happen on actual device.